# javascript - export default/import not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

This is my code:
Why is this not working?
The code is suppose to show the `h1` in the html file, but for some reason it doesn't do that for me.

Element.js :

```
import React from "react"
function Element() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Element
```

app.js :

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Element from './Element.js'

ReactDOM.render(<Element />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

the html code:

```
<script src="/index.js" type="text/babel"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

I looked at many solutions at stackoverflow but this bug it still doesn't work. I added `import React from "react"` and `import ReactDOM from "react-dom"` in both files but still same thing: nothing in the `return` statement doesn't show up, I've been struggling for hours. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: This isn't an `import`/`export` problem. You have `<script src="/index.js" type="text/babel"></script>`. That would mean that your code was being handled by the **client-side** Babel Standalone (not recommended where it can be avoided). I suspect you meant for your code to be transpiled during a build process. You'll have to configure that for it to happen (or start with a scaffolding tool like create-react-app).

Comment: Are you instancing react in app.js?

Comment: Could you post any screenshots of the errors that you are seeing on console?

Comment: Console errors should be [posted as text, not images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

Following things need to improve into your code-

1-Use of root level rendering things in index.js instead of app.js.

index.js

```
import React from "react";

import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App.js";  

ReactDOM.render(   
<App /> ,
document.getElementById("root")
);
```

2-Use App.js file to accumulate all other component into it.

App.js

import Element from './Element'

```
function App() {
return (
<div className='App'>
  <Element />
</div>
)
}
```

PS:  Learn the heirarchy of react and its flow .
This links may be helpful:

**React Rendering -**
https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html

**Introduction to react rendering**
https://medium.com/information-and-technology/an-introduction-to-react-rendering-9c24a96b838b

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there are three issues here. With the code provided, thats what I get.

1. As @T.J. Crowder mentioned in the comments, the script's `type` attribute needs a change. You can completely remove it too.
2. As far as I know, the latest ReactDOM package does not have a `render` method. You have to fitst create a root, and then render the app like so

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Element />);
```

3. Include the script after the `root` div element, coz the script when gets executed may not know the element with `id` root.

Answer (score 0):

I would re-do the app.js to

```js
import Element from './test'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Element />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

PS. also some links to the official documentation and how to use react https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html
https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html

PS 2: or if You would really like to do it in the old way

```js
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Element from './test'

function App() {
  return React.createElement('div', {}, React.createElement(Element))
}

export default App
```